# Input Queue Tracing with ETW Microsoft-Windows-Win32k

Tags: windows, event-log, c

I have UI lags when the machine is busy. When I click on different windows on my UI the selection is not changing which indicates a blocked message queue. After some time 20s or longer the click events get through.
I can trace with ETW the mouse click events and when with the Win32K ETW Provider when the blockade
did go away.

[image]

What I struggle with is how can I prove which other process was blocking my UI Input Queue? Are any of the many Microsoft-Windows-Win32k events containing the data I would need?

To try it out install the Windows Performance Toolkit and call

```
xperf -on proc_thread -start uisession -on Microsoft-Windows-Win32k:0xffffff
xperf -stop -stop uisession && xperf -merge c:\kernel.etl c:\user.etl c:\temp\win32ktrace.etl
```

Do I need a different bitmask and different events? If yes which one?
The other HookTracer Events are from my own tool ETWController (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=etwcontroler)  which traces to ETW all intercepted Mouse and Keyboard events. Besides that it also captures screenshots after every mouse click so I can see how the UI did look like which is very helpful for such issues.